# Select OnChange Javascript on Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, onchange

[image]

I want to make it so that when I click on one of the dropdowns, the value according to the record id in the related table immediately appears.
I want to make it so that when I click on one of the dropdowns, the value according to the record id in the related table immediately appears.
when "golongan" is selected then the value of "gaji pokok" automatically appears.
when "asisten ahli" is selected then the value of "tunjangan fungsional" automatically appears.
when "pembantu ketua | asisten ahli" is selected then the value of "tunjangan struktural" automatically appears.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="tambahgajiModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="tambahgajiModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="tambahfungsiModal">Tambah Gaji Karyawan</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="/gaji/insert" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="nama" type="text" class="form-control select2 @error('nama') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('nama') }}">
                                    <option>-- Nama Karyawan --</option>
                                    @foreach ($karyawan as $data)
                                    <option value="{{ $data->nama }}">{{ $data->nama }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('nama')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="gol" type="text" class="form-control select2 @error('gol') is-invalid @enderror" onchange="getddl()" value="{{ old('gol') }}">
                                    <option>-- Golongan dan M K G --</option>
                                    @foreach ($golongan as $data)
                                    <option value="{{ $data->gol }} | {{ $data->mkg }}">{{ $data->gol }} | {{ $data->mkg }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('gol')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="tunjangan_gol" type="text" placeholder="Gaji Pokok" class="form-control @error('tunjangan_gol') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('tunjangan_gol') }}" id="gol">
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('tunjangan_gol')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="jbt_fungsi" type="text" class="form-control select2 @error('jbt_fungsi') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('jbt_fungsi') }}">
                                    <option>-- Jabatan Fungsional --</option>
                                    @foreach ($fungsi as $data)
                                    <option value="{{ $data->jbt_fungsi }}">{{ $data->jbt_fungsi }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('gol')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="tunjangan_fungsi" type="text" placeholder="Tunjangan Fungsional" class="form-control @error('tunjangan_fungsi') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('tunjangan_fungsi') }}">
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('tunjangan_fungsi')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="jbt_struktur" type="text" class="form-control select2 @error('jbt_struktur') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('jbt_struktur') }}">
                                    <option>-- Jabatan Struktural & Fungsional --</option>
                                    @foreach ($struktur as $data)
                                    <option value="{{ $data->jbt_struktur }} | {{ $data->jbt_fungsi }}">{{ $data->jbt_struktur }} | {{ $data->jbt_fungsi }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('jbt_struktur')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="tunjangan_struktur" type="text" placeholder="Tunjangan Struktural" class="form-control @error('tunjangan_struktur') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('tunjangan_struktur') }}">
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('tunjangan_struktur')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="total_gaji" type="text" placeholder="Total Gaji" class="form-control @error('total_gaji') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('total_gaji') }}">
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('total_gaji')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to package it with Javascript onChange in laravel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I couldn't understand your language well, but you can do something like this with jquery

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
        <select  id="country-dropdown" class="form-control">
            <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
            @foreach ($countries as $data)
            <option value="{{$data->id}}">
                {{$data->name}}
            </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <select id="state-dropdown" class="form-control">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="city-dropdown" class="form-control">
        </select>
    </div>
```

you can leave the dependent dropdown empty, then get those depentdent dropdown through ajax like these:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        /*------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------
        Country Dropdown Change Event
        --------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------*/
        $('#country-dropdown').on('change', function () {
            var idCountry = this.value;
            $("#state-dropdown").html('');
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('api/fetch-states')}}",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    country_id: idCountry,
                    _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#state-dropdown').html('<option value="">-- Select State --</option>');
                    $.each(result.states, function (key, value) {
                        $("#state-dropdown").append('<option value="' + value
                            .id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
                    });
                    $('#city-dropdown').html('<option value="">-- Select City --</option>');
                }
            });
        });

        /*------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------
        State Dropdown Change Event
        --------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------*/
        $('#state-dropdown').on('change', function () {
            var idState = this.value;
            $("#city-dropdown").html('');
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('api/fetch-cities')}}",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    state_id: idState,
                    _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (res) {
                    $('#city-dropdown').html('<option value="">-- Select City --</option>');
                    $.each(res.cities, function (key, value) {
                        $("#city-dropdown").append('<option value="' + value
                            .id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

and declare the routes that you will call in url in ajax

```
Route::post('etch-states', [DropdownController::class, 
'fetchState']);
Route::post('fetch-cities', [DropdownController::class, 'fetchCity']);
```

In the controller do something like this:

```
public function fetchState(Request $request)
{
    $data['states'] = State::where("country_id", $request->country_id)
                            ->get(["name", "id"]);

    return response()->json($data);
}
/**
 * Write code on Method
 *
 * @return response()
 */
public function fetchCity(Request $request)
{
    $data['cities'] = City::where("state_id", $request->state_id)
                                ->get(["name", "id"]);
                                  
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Comment: i am sorry about that,
all that code written in one view file ?

Comment: yes, insert the script section before the end of your blade, or you can add it to another separate js file and pass the parameters.

Comment: what should i fill in the url part, if the data is called from database ?

Comment: make a api route, or simple web route then in that route function or controller function,
get the data from database and return as json, let me show you the controller example:
==========================
$data['states'] = State::where("country_id", $request->country_id)->get(["name", "id"]);
return response()->json($data);
==========================
then, show the data in blade.

Comment: let me add the controller part in the reply above, so you can understand well

Comment: very clear, thank you jazakallah khairan for your instructions